# Lebesgue Measure of a k-cell

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Working through Rudin's RCA construction (Theorem 2.20, p. 53) of the Lebesgue measure using the Riesz Representation Theorem. Rudin constructs a linear functional $\Lambda$ on $\operatorname{C}_c(\mathbb{R}^k)$ such that

$$\Lambda f := \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 2^{-nk} \sum\limits_{x \in P_n} f(x)$$
where $P_n$ is the set of all vectors of the form $x = (a_1/2^n,...,a_k/2^n)$ for $a_1,...,a_k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now let $W$ be an open $k$-cell. Rudin considers the set $S_r = \{ Q \in \Omega_r: \overline{Q} \subset W\}$, where $\Omega_r$ is the set of all boxes of the form $Q = \{ x: a_i \leq x_i < a_i + 2^{-r}, a_i \in P_r, 1 \leq i \leq k\}$. He then defines
$$E_r = \bigcup\limits_{Q \in S_r} Q$$
and applies Urysohn's Lemma to obtain a function $0 \leq f_r \leq 1$ such that $f[\overline{E}_r] = 1$, $\operatorname{supp}(f)\subseteq W$, and $\overline{E}_r \subseteq \operatorname{supp}(f)$. Note that $\overline{E}_r $ is compact.

He then asserts without proof that

> $$\operatorname{vol}(E_r) \leq \Lambda f_r \leq \Lambda g_r \leq
> \operatorname{vol}(W)$$

where $g_r := \max\{f_i: 1 \leq i \leq r\}$. How do we establish this inequality? It would seem a priori that it would arise out of demonstrating $\operatorname{vol}(E_r) \leq \Lambda_n f$ for all $n$, but I have so far been unsuccessful in this matter.

Using Urysohn's Lemma we obtained that $\chi_{\overline{E}_r} \leq f \leq \chi_W$, which may yield another route.

As a secondary question, are there any other good sources for a construction of the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^k$ using the Riesz Representation Theorem? All of the other standard texts, e.g. Royden, on the subject construct an outer Lebesgue measure and extend using the results of Caratheodory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$E_r$ is a union of $P_r$-boxes, and since $W$ is a $k$-cell, so is $E_r$.

For $s \geqslant r$, consider

$$\Lambda_s(f) = 2^{-sk}\sum_{x \in P_s} f(x) \geqslant 2^{-sk} \sum_{\substack{x \in P_s\\x+[0,\,2^{-s})^k \subset E_r}} f(x) = 2^{-sk}\sum_{\substack{x \in P_s\\x+[0,\,2^{-s})^k \subset E_r}} 1 = \operatorname{vol}(E_r),$$

since the $P_s$-boxes contained in $E_r$ are disjoint, their union is $E_r$, and each has volume $2^{-sk}$.

Thus $\Lambda_s(f) \geqslant \operatorname{vol}(E_r)$ for all $s \geqslant r$, hence the same holds for $\Lambda(f)$.

I can't answer your secondary question, Rudin is the only source I know that takes this approach.

Comment: 1) You claim that $E_r$ is $k$-cell? 2) Can you explain more detailed your inequality is seems quite confusing?

Comment: @RFZ Yes, $E_r$ is a $k$-cell (a half-open $k$-cell). Let $W = \prod_{i = 1}^k (a_i,b_i)$. Then $E_r = \prod_{i = 1}^k [u_i, v_i)$, where $u_i = 2^{-r}\cdot (\lfloor 2^r\cdot a_i\rfloor+1)$ is the smallest integer multiple of $2^{-r}$ larger than $a_i$, and $v_i = 2^{-r}\cdot(\lceil 2^r\cdot b_i\rceil - 1)$ is the largest integer multiple of $2^{-r}$ smaller than $b_i$. The inequality comes from the fact that we drop some terms from the sum, and all values $f(x)$ are non-negative. The non-negativity implies that dropping terms from the sum cannot make the sum larger (it remains the same if all

Comment: dropped terms are $0$, and if at least one dropped term is strictly positive, the remaining sum becomes strictly smaller than the full sum). We keep only those terms $f(x)$ in the sum where $x$ is the "lower left" corner of a box that is completely contained in $E_r$, and by definition of $f$ [should have been $f_r$, since we have different functions for different $r$, but the index was already dropped once in the question, and I accidentally copied that], we have $f(x) = 1$ for all these $x$.

Comment: May I ask you why $\Lambda g_r\leq \text{vol}(W)$? Here's my approach:
Let's take a look at $\Lambda_n g_r$. By definition $$\Lambda_n g_r=2^{-nk}\sum \limits_{x\in P_n}g_r(x)=2^{-nk}\sum \limits_{x\in P_n\cap W}g_r(x)+2^{-nk}\sum \limits_{x\in P_n, x\notin W}g_r(x).$$ But the second sum is zero since $x\notin W$ then $f_i(x)=0$ hence $g_r(x)=0$.  I tried the summanf of the first sum estimate by 1 but it does not give to us this that the first sum is less that $\text{vol} (W)$

Comment: @RFZ So far, so good. But you don't quite use $g_r(x)\leqslant1$ for $x\in P_n\cap W$. Since $\operatorname{supp}g_r$ is a compact subset of $W$, there is a compact $k$-cell $K_r$ with $\operatorname{supp}g_r\subset K_r\subset W$. You then use $g_r(x)\leqslant1$ for $x\in P_n\cap K_r$ (and $g_r(x)=0$ for $x\in P_n\setminus K_r$). For $n$ large enough, every box $\prod_{i=1}^k [x_i,x_i+2^{-n})$ with $x\in P_n\cap K_r$ is contained in $W$, and for these $n$ it follows that $\Lambda_n g_r\leqslant \operatorname{vol}(W)$. Taking the limit, $\Lambda g_r\leqslant\operatorname{vol}(W)$ follows.

Comment: Can you clarify please one moment. I can't understand why exists compact $k-cell$ $K_r$ with above property?

Comment: @RFZ For $\delta > 0$, let $U_{\delta} = \prod_{i = 1}^k (a_i + \delta, b_i - \delta)$. For $0 < \delta_1 < \delta_2$, we have $\overline{U}_{\delta_2} \subset U_{\delta_1}$, and $W = \bigcup_{\delta > 0} U_{\delta}$, so in particular the $U_{\delta}$ cover $\operatorname{supp} g_r$. By compactness of $\operatorname{supp} g_r$, a finite family covers the support, and since the $U_{\delta}$ are nested, that finite family has a largest member, so $\operatorname{supp} g_r \subset U_{\varepsilon}$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$. Then one can choose $K_r = \overline{U}_{\varepsilon}$.

Answer (score 0):

To prove $\Lambda g_r \leq \text{vol}(W)$; Since $f_i \prec W$ we have $f_i\leq \chi_W$ for $i=1,...,r$, therefore since $g_r=\max(f_1,...,f_r)$ it follows $g_r\leq \chi_W$ and $\Lambda g_r\leq \Lambda \chi_W$. Since $\Lambda$ is just the Riemann integral it follows that $\Lambda \chi_W$ is the volume of $W$, therefore $\Lambda g_r\leq \text{vol}(W)$